# How can I ONLY grab the price value of selected crypto currency

Tags: javascript, html, json, binance

**GOAL**: ONLY Grab Price Value of Selected Crypto Currency! Using the [Binance Public API](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md)

**Problem**: Returns a whole JSON string rather than just the selected currency's price.

**Code**:

```js
  var burl = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol='
  var symbol = 'BTCUSDT'
  var url = burl + symbol
  var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()

  ourRequest.open('GET', url, true)
  ourRequest.onload = function() {
    console.log(ourRequest.responseText)
  }
  ourRequest.send()
```

Now do be fair I do know I can use `[.replace()][2]` or `[.split()][3] + [.join()][4]` to only get the price however I do believe there's an easier way than going thru with that method.

```js
var burl = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol='
var symbol = 'BTCUSDT'
var url = burl + symbol
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()

ourRequest.open('GET', url, true)
ourRequest.onload = function() {
  var str = ourRequest.responseText
  str = str.split('{"symbol":"BTCUSDT","price":"').join('')
  str = str.split('"}').join('')
  document.body.innerHTML = str
}
ourRequest.send()
```

My question is this, How can I ONLY grab the price value of selected crypto currency as text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do like this

```js
  var burl = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol='
    var symbol = 'BTCUSDT'
    var url = burl + symbol
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    
    ourRequest.open('GET', url, true)
    ourRequest.onload = function() {
      var str = ourRequest.responseText
      var strobj = JSON.parse(str)
     document.body.innerHTML = strobj.price
    
    }
    ourRequest.send()
```

Comment: ROFL wow I can't believe I didn't think of that

Answer (score 2):

Same as @EtsukoSusui but using fetch

```js
const burl = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol='
const symbol = 'BTCUSDT'
const url = burl + symbol
const res = await fetch(url)
const { price } = await res.json()
document.body.innerHTML = price
```